# Call Base functions from Child in VB.net

Tags: vb.net-2010

How to call the base functions in vb.net?

```
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Box
    Public length As Double   ' Length of a box
    Public breadth As Double   ' Breadth of a box
    Public height As Double    ' Height of a box
    Public function setLength(ByVal len As Double)
        length = len
    End Sub
    Public Sub setBreadth(ByVal bre As Double)
        breadth = bre
    End Sub
    Public Sub setHeight(ByVal hei As Double)
        height = hei
    End Sub
    Public Function getVolume() As Double
        Return length * breadth * height
     End Function
 End Class
```

It says syntax error when I use MyBase to call the base functions

```
Public Class myChild : Inherits Box
    'box 1 specification
    MyBase.setLength(6.0)
    MyBase.setBreadth(7.0)
    MyBase.setHeight(5.0)

    'box 2 specification
    MyBase.setLength(12.0)
    MyBase.setBreadth(13.0)
    MyBase.setHeight(10.0) 

    'volume of box 1
    volume = MyBase.getVolume()
    Console.WriteLine("Volume of Box1 : {0}", volume)

    'volume of box 2
    volume = MyBase.getVolume()
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `MyBase` from there as the object hasn't yet been constructed.

A better implementation would be:

*Box.vb*

```
Public Class Box
    Private mLength As Double   ' Length of a box
    Private mBreadth As Double   ' Breadth of a box
    Private mHeight As Double    ' Height of a box

    Public Sub New(ByVal length As Double, ByVal breadth As Double, ByVal height As Double)
        Me.mLength = length
        Me.mBreadth = breadth
        Me.mHeight = height

    End Sub
    Public Property Length As Double
        Get
            Return Me.mLength
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Double)
            Me.mLength = value
        End Set
    End Property

Public Property Breadth As Double
    Get
        Return Me.mBreadth
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Double)
        Me.mBreadth = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Height As Double
    Get
        Return Me.mHeight
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Double)
        Me.mHeight = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Function getVolume() As Double
    Return Length * Breadth * Height
End Function
End Class
```

*Child.vb*

```
Public Class Child : Inherits Box

    Public Sub New(ByVal length As Double, ByVal breadth As Double, ByVal height As Double)
        MyBase.New(length, breadth, height)
    End Sub

End Class
```

*Example*

```
 Sub Main()
        Dim box1 As New Child(6.0, 7.0, 5.0)
        Dim box2 As New Child(12.0, 13.0, 10.0)

        Console.WriteLine("box1 volume is: {0}", box1.getVolume())
        Console.WriteLine("box2 volume is: {0}", box2.getVolume())
    End Sub
```

Comment: Hmmm. so in vb.net, there is no need to use include/require function to use other file? just like php using include/require function.

Comment: @J.Ignacio If all the files are under the same namespace, then you do not need to explicitly import the file. My VB.NET is very scratchy, but I do think you'll need to import if the file is in a different namespace- although VB is very forgiving of most things.